# Где в предложении подлежащее и сказуемое?

Tags: синтаксис

Есть предложение: "Человек он очень добрый, но с понятиями довольно странными". Где тут подлежащее, а где сказуемое?

Answer (score 2):

Подлежащее — ***он,***

сказуемое — ***человек добрый, (но) с понятиями странными.***

> **§ 2340. <...>   Если подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, то
>   существительное из состава сказуемого может быть вынесено в начало
>   предложения** в качестве первой части темы, выделяемой повышением тона:
>   *Человек он был // скромный; Женщина она была // удивительная; Вопрос это был // нелегкий; Невежда он был // круглый; Работник он был //
>   первоклассный.*
>
> http://rusgram.narod.ru/2330-2352.html

P.S.
***Человек*** в разбираемом предложении — слово абстрактного значения, сказуемым без определений рассматриваться не может.